# Can we use RUN cd /app instead of using WORKDIR /app in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I want to use RUN cd /app instead of WORKDIR /app in my dockerfile.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can `mkdir /app` and then `cd /app`. `WORKDIR` is used to specify the directory whenever you `exec` `bash` to connect to container or the working directory when container start.